# How to get all the recent records which are inserted today in 1 specific database having many tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, record

The purpose is to know 'which table is used in daily working'.

As titled, the DB has many tables and each table has also many columns.

I can query in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2(Server is 2005) with Windows Authentification mode(system administrator). I can also access to LDF file and to SQL Server log.

Actually, previously, the working table was A but suddenly changed to some table else.

Is there a way to query through all tables in 1 specific database ?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this query saved. It returns `table_name` and `last_user_update` :

```
SELECT 
      [db_name] = d.name
    , [table_name] = SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '.' + o.name
    , s.last_user_update
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s
JOIN sys.databases d ON s.database_id = d.database_id
JOIN sys.objects o ON s.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
    AND s.last_user_update IS NOT NULL
    AND s.last_user_update BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: oh, thank you for your answer ! Does this query run on master DB and is for 1 recent week? can you explain how this works? This query runs without error but no results now..

Comment: Why would you ping master? Its a simple query which fetches records from `sys.db_index_usage_stats`, `sys.databases` and `sys.objects`. Basically these tables store execution data. We are just fetching them. You can modify last statement to your need to get last week data.

Comment: oh, just working now...I inserted a test record. Thank you ! :)

Comment: To test it, perform some insert/delete/update in a table and run this query. You'll get a gist of it.